# Intervlan routing in HP Procurve 2900 not working

Tags: hp, vlan, hp-procurve

Heya networking gurus!

I am building a Proof of concept that requires doing some wacky things.  All is going well except I can not seem to get my intervlan routing working.

Here is a diagram of what is built:

[Network DIagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysvuA.jpg)

Each "Node" has 2 nic cards in it.  One for management using DHCP the other static for the 10.10.x.x networks.  The Nodes are Ubuntu 14.

Node 1 has a Gateway IP of 10.10.101.1
Node 2 has a Gateway IP of 10.10.102.1

Here is my HP Procurve config:

```
Running configuration:

; J9049A Configuration Editor; Created on release #T.13.84

hostname "ProCurve Switch 2900-24G"
module 1 type J86wwA
module 3 type J90XXA
no stack
ip routing
vlan 1
   name "DEFAULT_VLAN"
   untagged 1-24,A1-A4
   ip address 192.168.168.201 255.255.255.0
   exit
vlan 101
   name "Node-1"
   ip address 10.10.101.1 255.255.255.0
   tagged 1,24
   exit
vlan 102
   name "Node-2"
   ip address 10.10.102.1 255.255.255.0
   tagged 1,24
   exit
no ip ssh
snmp-server community "public" Unrestricted
spanning-tree
management-vlan 1
password manager
```

Here is the ip route from the Procurve:

```
ProCurve Switch 2900-24G# show ip route

                                                                       IP 
Route Entries

  Destination        Gateway         VLAN Type      Sub-Type   Metric     Dist.
  ------------------ --------------- ---- --------- ---------- ---------- -----
  10.10.101.0/24     Node-1          101  connected            1          0
  10.10.102.0/24     Node-2          102  connected            1          0
  127.0.0.0/8        reject               static               0          0
  127.0.0.1/32       lo0                  connected            1          0
  192.168.168.0/24   DEFAULT_VLAN    1    connected            1          0
```

from Node-1 I can ping 10.10.101.1

```
PING 10.10.101.1 (10.10.101.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.10.101.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=100 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.101.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=50.4 ms
```

Trying to ping 10.10.102.1 does not ping.

But if I go to Node-2 I can ping both 10.10.101.1 & 10.10.102.1:

```
appo@Node-2:~$ ping 10.10.101.1
PING 10.10.101.1 (10.10.101.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.10.101.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=50.4 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.101.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=50.4 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.101.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=50.4 ms

--- 10.10.101.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 50.410/50.423/50.432/0.183 ms

appo@Node-2:~$ ping 10.10.102.1
PING 10.10.102.1 (10.10.102.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.10.102.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=50.3 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.102.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=50.3 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.102.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=50.3 ms

--- 10.10.102.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 50.361/50.374/50.387/0.183 ms
```

What I would like to do would be able to is have inter vlan routing so that vlan 101 & 102 can see eachother.  I will need to ssh from one node to the other.   I have been looking on the forums and hp documentation but I can't figure out why the procurve is not routing the 2 vlans.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems configure of switch is OK. Please, show **ip route** on Node-1 and Node-2.

Answer (score 0):

Well ladies and gentlemen I figured it out myself.

I needed to add static routes to my Nodes (ubuntu) so that all 10.10.x.x traffic flows through the 2nd nic card.

On my Node-1 I did:

```
ip route add 10.10.0.0/16 via 10.10.101.1 dev ens192
```

And on Node-2 I did:

```
ip route add 10.10.0.0/16 via 10.10.102.1 dev ens192
```

Comment: /16 ? It's just need add /24: 10.10.201.0/24 (on Node-1) and 10.10.101.0/24 (on Node-2).

Comment: Yes.  But I will be adding 24 more nodes.  10.10.101-124.  SO I went ahead and did the /16